# Salesforce Uploading attachment in custom page and have a type as Feed Attachment

Tags: salesforce, custom-controls

I have the following code and I get error 
Errors

Body: Required fields are missing: [Body]
Error uploading attachment

```
   { public with sharing class FileUploadCtrl {

  public Attachment attachment {
  get {
      if (attachment == null)
        attachment = new Attachment();
      return attachment;
    }
  set;
  }

  public PageReference upload() {

    Property__feed p = new Property__feed();

    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    //attachment.ParentId = 'a01o0000000QkQf'; // the record the file is attached to
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;

    try {

      feedItem f = new feedItem();
      f.ParentId = 'a01o0000000QkQfAAK';
      ///f.RelatedRecordId = attachment.Id;
      insert f;
      insert attachment;
      attachment.ParentId = f.Id;
      update attachment;

    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
      return null;
    } finally {
      attachment = new Attachment(); 
    }

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
    return null;
  }
}
}
```

I want to have it as a feeditem attachment, its a personal apex uploader 
basically I want to change the type of this to Feed Attachments .. instead of Attachments
and here is the picture sample 
[image]

Comment: Whats your question? the error says you haven't set the body, and your code hasn't set the body.

Comment: @superfell Right now When  I fix this error and save the file it goes to related Object ... Note and Attachments .... it get saved as Attachment under the type, but I want it to be saved as Feed Attachment so I can query it somewhere else... Feed Attachment will be saved in the Files Folder where I can search for anything that its been saved ... Doest that make saense?

Comment: @superfell I added a picture to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create FeedItem and link the content fields to the attachment body etc. Are you looking for this??

```
public void addFeedItemAttachment(){
attachment.parentId=accId;
insert attachment;

FeedItem FI = new FeedItem();
FI.ParentId = accId;
FI.Body = 'Attachment added';
FI.ContentData = attachment.body;
FI.ContentFileName = attachment.Name;
insert FI;}
```

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: I did that and it worked actually, but do you know how I can get LinkUrl to every attachment that I have ? I want my page to show the URL of the feed too, so If I upload a picture , show me the URL to the picture LinkURl and this doesnt work ...  <apex:column headerValue="URL" value="{!item.feed_Url}"/>